# Revert git remote accidentally pushed repository changes

Tags: git, git-remote

How could be possible to remove accidentally pushed repository from a remote origin?

Before push there where two independent repositories with own history
e.g. :

> Repo1: Commit1--Commit2--Commit3<--Head
>
> Repo2: Commit1--Commit2<--Head

After adding additional remote which refers Repo1 repository to Repo2 and pushed all Repo2 changes to Repo1 remote, Repo1 starts looking like this:

> Repo1:
> Repo2Commit1--Repo2Commit2-- --Repo1Commit1--Repo1Commit2--Repo1Commit3<--Head

So it appears as one master branch with two independent commit history sequences that not related to each other.

In addition `git log` doesn't show all the commits, it shows only history for the one independent sequence.

Is there a way to revert Repo2 commits from Repo1. So it will look as before e.g:

> Repo1: Commit1--Commit2--Commit3<--Head

Any ideas?

[image: How is it possible?]

Comment: It impossible that one branch has *two independent commit history sequences*. What command did you use to *push all Repo2 changes to Repo1*?

Comment: git remote add ...
git push <Remote name>

Comment: `git remote add` does not push anything. I suppose you are confused with two remote master branches? If you don't need the repo2 remote, try removing it with `git remote rm repo2`.

Comment: @fracz Before pushing any changes to the Repo1 I have added Repo1 as remote to Repo2 and execute git push Repo1 on Repo2. As the result I see two independent sequences in Repo1. Please note that in Repo1 there is only one remote for fetching and pushing

Answer (score 0):

You see two independent sequences because the repos are "unrelated" - not the same fork.

`git reflog` on Repo2 might be helpful in this situation.

just clone the Repo2 to another directory and run `git reflog` there. You will see sequential changes made on the repository. After that you can just hard reset to wanted commit (history in the reflog contains hash of each change) and force push it back to the remote Repo2.

But I am not sure what you wanted to accomplish. So be sure to make a backups of both repositories.

Comment: Repo2 is good and doesn't need any changes but Repo1 does. git reflog shows changes only in local repository but the problem is that the remote repository Repo1 has an additional unrelated history that visible in SourceTree but invisible on the web or with any git command. So the aim is to remove Repo2 history from Repo1. Also, commits sequences are unrelated and not connected to each other.

Comment: And how about if you create a new remote repository and try to push your branches from Repo1 into that? It might solve the problem, it seems like you have the unrelated history only localy. Just keep in mind you need to push only wanted branches and not run `git push --all` So far I dont know how to remove unrelated commits from the history.